# How to parse guess_language to read 30000 tweets?

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I am using [guess_language](https://bitbucket.org/spirit/guess_language/src/default/) to detect the language of the tweets for a school project. I used pandas to read the .csv file. I have around 30000 rows.

However, my problem is that the guess language can only read one tweet at a time.

guess_language("Top story: â€˜Massive Mental Health Crisisâ€™ ")

'en'

I am very new at python and been trying to figure out the loop and if statements for this for almost a day now and they keep just returning one tweet.

Thank you and apologies if the question is lame.

---

**I used the code suggested below by Kareem.**

from guess_language import guess_language resdf = nodupdf[ nodupdf['text'].apply(guess_language) == 'en' ]

It worked for the small file (100 csv), but when I applied it on the bigger one. It gave me this error.

TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) in 9 10 for chunk in noeng: ---> 11 chunk['text'].apply(guess_language)== 'en'

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds) 4040 else: 4041 values = self.astype(object).values -> 4042 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype) 4043 4044 if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\guess_language__init__.py in guess_language(text, hints) 322 """Return the ISO 639-1 language code. 323 """ --> 324 words = WORD_RE.findall(text[:MAX_LENGTH].replace("’", "'")) 325 return identify(words, find_runs(words), hints) 326

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

---

**Thinking it was a memory error, I used chunk.**

noeng=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\jean\nodupdf.csv', chunksize=10) for chunk in noeng: chunk['text'].apply(guess_language)== 'en'

I still got the same error.

Comment: So what you are trying to achieve is to  apply this function ```guess_language``` on every row of the csv file right ?  if you could provide a sample of your csv file that would be helpfull

Comment: Yes, apply the guess_language on every row, so it will only give me the English tweets.  Like this one: guess_language("Top story: â€˜Massive Mental Health Crisisâ€™ ")

'en'

I have a 30000 rows and 12 columns. The tweets are under the column 'text'. My data frame is called newdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch every and process them basically like this

```
resdf =  newdf[ newdf['text'].apply(guess_language) == 'en' ]
```

the resdf should contain the rows of the original that had a classification of english for its tweets.

The function `apply` should apply your function `guess_language` on every single tweet and return the column values after being classified, then we use that to get only the indexes of rows who had `en` as classification.

Comment: Thanks Kareem but I got this error: TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Could you include a sample (1-5 records) of your data to test that? This is like a pseudo code now just to give the main idea

Comment: Also attach the stack trace if your error, maybe it's a special case in some record.

Comment: Hi! I posted a new 'answer' under this, instead of a comment because it was a bit long. Thank you so much

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure I can see the other answer, but if you managed to solve the problem in that answer then that's great news

Comment: It got deleted. I put the error and what I did above (see my original post above). I hope that works. I still don't know how to use stackoverflow

Comment: Could you try adding this condition ```if type(chunk) is pd.DataFrame:``` before running the function on chunked data frame, I think the data may contain some corrupted records

Comment: The other issue could be that some of the rows has the text field as float instead of being actual string

Comment: You could use this
```df =  df[df['text'].apply(lambda x:  isinstance(x, str))]```
to remove any row containing a float value for text or non string value

Comment: if type(chunk) is pd.DataFrame: still gave the same error.  and the second one gave me this error: TypeError: 'TextFileReader' object is not subscriptable

Comment: the second one should be applied to each chunk dataframe not the df holding all chunks. if you are using no chunks then apply it to the df directly

Comment: OMG! You're amazing! Thank you. It worked! It was just a bit slow probably because of my computer. THANK YOU SO MUCH.